# Deploy Azure function app using azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, playwright

I have a function app responsible for taking in a config object, rendering a highcharts graph and returning a png of the result. This works fine if my function app is running on an app service plan, but does not when it's running on a consumption plan. On a consumption plan, I get the following error:

> Error: browserType.launch: Failed to launch browser: Error: spawn /home/site/wwwroot/browsers/chromium-844399/chrome-linux/chrome EACCES

This is my function app:

```js
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";
import path from "path";
import { mergeDeepLeft } from "ramda";
import { chromium, ChromiumBrowser, Page } from "playwright-chromium";
import { i18n } from "./highChartsLang";

// To avoid errors in page.evaluate when referring to function only existing in template
var window: any;

const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (
  context: Context,
  req: HttpRequest
): Promise<void> {
  const res = await generateChart(req.body);
  context.res = res;
};

async function generateChart(body: any) {
  try {
    // Check config
    const { config, width, height, lang = "EN" } = body;
    if (!(!!width && !!height)) {
      return { status: 400, body: "Both width and height need to be set." };
    }

    // Setup browser - THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR HAPPENS
    const browser: ChromiumBrowser = await chromium.launch({
      headless: true,
      args: [
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
        "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
      ],
    });

    // Render chart
    const page: Page = await browser.newPage({ viewport: { width, height } });
    const pagePath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), "templating", "template.html");
    await page.goto(`file://${pagePath}`);
    await page.evaluate(
      ([chartConfig, language]) => window.renderChart(chartConfig, language),
      [
        mergeDeepLeft(config, {
          chart: { animation: false },
          credits: false,
          plotOptions: { series: { animation: false } },
        }),
        typeof lang === "string" ? i18n[lang.toUpperCase()] : lang,
      ]
    );

    // Take screenshot and return png image
    const file = await page.screenshot();

    // Clean up
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
    return { "Content-Type": "image/png", body: file };
  } catch (err) {
    return { status: 500, body: err.toString() };
  }
}

export default httpTrigger;
```

This is how I build my function app:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - 'master'

# Using latest ubuntu image
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    displayName: 'Use Node version 12.x'
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '12.x'
      checkLatest: true

  # Install and build
  - script: |
      set -e

      # Set the install directory of chromium browser
      PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/browsers

      # Install and build
      npm ci
      npm run build

      # In case the agent does not respect the env var above, 
      # copy the browser from the npm-cache and into the local directory
      cp -R ~/.cache/ms-playwright $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/browsers

      # Trying desperately to avoid EACCESS error
      sudo chmod -R 755 $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/browsers
    displayName: 'Install dependencies and build'

  # Archive result
  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    displayName: 'Archive files'
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
      includeRootFolder: false

  # Publish result
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
```

This pipeline installs, builds and archives the app in a zip file. We then have a release pipeline which performs a deploy on the archive:

```yaml
steps:
- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
  displayName: 'Deploy Azure Function App'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(Parameters.AzureSubscription)'
    appType: '$(Parameters.AppType)'
    appName: '$(Parameters.AppName)'
    runtimeStack: 'NODE|12'
    appSettings: '-PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH /home/site/wwwroot/browsers'
    configurationStrings: '-PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH /home/site/wwwroot/browsers'
```

**UPDATE**

I managed to deploy this in a working state using vsCode. That means the problem is in the pipeline. So at this point, I'll rephrase the question slightly and ask; how can I deploy this FA using an Azure Devops Pipeline?

Comment: Have you referred to the blog : https://dev.to/azure/running-headless-chromium-in-azure-functions-with-puppeteer-and-playwright-2fgk?

Comment: Yes. That's where I got the tip on setting the `PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH`. Only instead of setting it to `0`, which would create a <root>/0 folder, I set it to `browsers` which creates a <root>/browsers folder. This works fine when I run it locally, and when I run it on an app service plan. But not in a consumption plan.

Comment: And also, I do not deploy using VSCode, like the blog suggests. I deploy using an azure pipeline.

Comment: Does 14+ version work for you? - Check this GH issue: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/2264

Comment: This got me thinking, because when I deploy using VSCode, logs state that it actually uses node v14. So I changed the build agent to use v14 and I set the `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION`=~14 in the function app properties. Ran the build pipeline and the release pipeline, but no good. Same error.

Comment: You could try to use `sudo chmod -R 775` or  `sudo chmod -R 777` to set the permission for the file. Please check if it has the same issue.

Comment: That's what I'm doing in the last line of the `-script` in the build pipeline.

Comment: Did you manage to get playwright running using azure devops pipelines to build and deploy? I finally managed to get the browser binaries to be installed and read from node_modules (by setting PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=0 to both pipeline and function app). But when I try to launch the browser I get error: `Error: browserType.launch: Failed to launch: Error: spawn /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/playwright-chromium/.local-browsers/chromium-907428/chrome-linux/chrome EACCES`

Comment: That's the exact same place I crashed @ronkot. Works great when deployed using vsCode and the Azure function extension, but I cannot reproduce how the extension builds using a pipeline.